# What does "exit onto" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I don't understand **exit onto** in the following sentences:

> - Target is east and north of you, looks like Highway 56 to 17. Will intercept him if he stays on 17. Go east on 56 off Highway 2.
> - What?
> - You're going to **exit onto** Highway 56.

Does it mean the target is in Highway 56 and about to go to Highway 17, but the follower will intercept him if he goes to Highway 17, so he has to exit Highway 2 (currently he is in Highway 2) to go to Highway 56 to catch the target?

It's a part of the movie **Sicario**, I don't know if I can post a torrent link here.

Comment: What's the source of those sentences? A TV show or movie? Please include it with a link (if possible).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I interpret the dialog

> "Target is east and north of you, looks like [if you take] Highway 56
>   to 17. [you] Will intercept him if he stays on 17. Go east on 56
>   off Highway 2."

[image]

Comment: You are the best!

Comment: +1 excellent diagram.  (Though I find it much more likely that both "you" and "the target" should be moving south toward 56; that would make the total distance traveled by both more nearly equal, making the intercept much more likely than if "you" have to cover over twice the distance in the same time.  However, that's an extremely minor nitpick.  :-) )